# Grep only one word not a whole string

Tags: grep, disk-usage

I'm writing a simple script to monitoring the disk space in the / partition
and I want to grep only numbers in my output.

```
tabbi@tabbi:~/scripts$ df -h / 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       234G  7,6G  214G   4% /
```

Let's say I want to remove the % from the Use column (or remove it everywhere); when I use `df -h / | grep -v '%'` nothing is printed.

How can I exclude the % symbol from my output?

Comment: Please let us know what the actual output should look like. You say you "just want numbers"...

Comment: With GNU df, see also the `--output=used` option

Comment: Also: [bash string to int](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/48947) and [how to print just the 'use%' column with all use % values by 'df -k' command](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/348574)

Answer (score 4):

[`grep -v`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) removes any *line* matching the given string; so in your case, any line containing “%” is deleted, in its entirety.

To remove the character only, use [`tr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html):

```
df -h / | tr -d %
```

Comment: Beware the df header line and the Gs, that should be:  `df -h / | tr -d %G | tail -1`

Comment: We don’t know what the OP really wants, do we? I’m basing my answer on “How can I exclude the % symbol from my output?” And to avoid issues with G, M etc. the better approach is to drop the `-h` option.

Comment: The question could be better worded, for sure. Complain to the people doing moderation for being so lax. <grin>

Answer (score 1):

You can get the / directory usage, without "%", with `awk`. Basically, the `awk` in following command:

- Selects the last line of output, to account for the df header - END;
- deletes "%";
- outputs the *fifth* field (print $5).

  ```
  df -h / | awk '  END { gsub("%",""); print $5 } '
  ```

Running it:

```
$ df -h / | awk '  END { gsub("%",""); print $5 } '
4
```

Or to get all numbers:

```
$ df -h / | awk '  END { gsub("%",""); gsub("G",""); print $2" "$3" "$4" "$5 } '
234 7,6 214 4
```

Comment: @StephenKitt Works well without it...why the -P? df -h is not being affected by -P , only `df` default output.

Comment: @StephenKitt I have never seen two lines in `df`and *it seems* not affecting `df -h`. Will investigate that, thanks.

Comment: @StephenKitt /* Note the SOURCE_FIELD used to be displayed on it's own line
             if (!posix_format && mbswidth (cell) > 20), but that
             functionality was probably more problematic than helpful,
             hence changed in commit v8.10-40-g99679ff.  */

Comment: Wow, nice, it’s only been seven years or so! We need to update a bunch of answers here ;-).